# Azure Functions with ServiceBus:the operation was canceled

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've just deployed an update for my Azure Functions: there are different functions with timer or servicebus trigger. I noticed in the last couple of days an error related to ServiceBus

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusCommunicationException - The operation was canceled.

[image]

I don't know if this is happening when the function receives a message or there is something else.

The function is defined like

```
[FunctionName("createInvoiceListFromServiceBus")]
public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("invoice.requests.bulk", "requests", Connection = "AccountingServiceBusConnection")] 
        string myQueueItem,
        [ServiceBus("invoice.pdf.requests", Connection = "AccountingServiceBusConnection")] 
        IAsyncCollector<dynamic> pdfServiceBusRequests,
        [ServiceBus("invoice.paid.requests", Connection = "AccountingServiceBusConnection")] 
        IAsyncCollector<dynamic> paidServiceBusRequests)
    {
    }
```

This is the packages I'm using

```
<PackageReference Include="AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle" Version="3.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" Version="3.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.1.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Xero.Api.SDK.Core" Version="1.1.4" />
```

Here the full error description.

```
[
   {
      "parsedStack":[
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+<OnReceiveAsync>d__86.MoveNext",
            "level":0,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":1,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
            "level":2,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
            "level":3,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+<>c__DisplayClass64_0+<<ReceiveAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext",
            "level":4,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":5,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
            "level":6,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy+<RunOperation>d__19.MoveNext",
            "level":7,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":8,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy+<RunOperation>d__19.MoveNext",
            "level":9,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":10,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
            "level":11,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
            "level":12,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+<ReceiveAsync>d__64.MoveNext",
            "level":13,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":14,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
            "level":15,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
            "level":16,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+<ReceiveAsync>d__62.MoveNext",
            "level":17,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":18,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
            "level":19,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
            "level":20,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageReceivePump+<<MessagePumpTaskAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext",
            "level":21,
            "line":0
         }
      ],
      "severityLevel":"Information",
      "outerId":"0",
      "message":"The operation was canceled.",
      "type":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusCommunicationException",
      "id":"65258033"
   },
   {
      "parsedStack":[
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":0,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End",
            "level":1,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ReceivingAmqpLink.EndReceiveMessages",
            "level":2,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+<>c__DisplayClass86_0.<OnReceiveAsync>b__1",
            "level":3,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic",
            "level":4,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
            "level":5,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
            "level":6,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
            "method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
            "level":7,
            "line":0
         },
         {
            "assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7e34167dcc6d6d8c",
            "method":"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver+<OnReceiveAsync>d__86.MoveNext",
            "level":8,
            "line":0
         }
      ],
      "severityLevel":"Information",
      "outerId":"65258033",
      "message":"The operation was canceled.",
      "type":"System.OperationCanceledException",
      "id":"65736993"
   }
]
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue ? We are having similar errors from .NET core applications executed as docker containers. You may find useful my own github issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/18035

Comment: this error happens when the receiver is performing the "receive" operation over the AMQP link. If the connection between the receiver application and the message broker is damaged / closed while the recive operation is performed then this error happens.

Comment: Based on what the azure service team stated on my github issue, it seems that the .NET core SDK has been designed to gracefully handle this scenario via retry. So basically, the failed operation is retried (I guess that a brand new connection and a brand new AMQP link is established, in order to retry the operation). So basically it's all handled by the SDK.

Comment: What we are basically missing ris the underlying cause of this connection issues between the consuming application and the azure service bus. We are having this issue only when we deploy our application inside of kubernetes cluster (AKS). The same application deployed as an azure app service works fine and these errors don't pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Is the error transient?  Then, most likely it's some kind of connectivity issue between your application and one of it's dependencies. Error `The operation was canceled` indicates an async task that was cancelled, or most likely **timed out**.
https://www.asptricks.net/2019/10/task-cancellationtoken-net-c-example.html

For timeout hunting ... Looking at the `pasredStack` it looks like code that timed out was using `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver`.  From your main main `run()` method, it seems safe to deduce that the one of the two actions using the `AccountingServiceBusConnection` may have timed out.

In an effort to reproduce the error, I would suggest trying this operation while simulataneously load testing those underlying resources: `pdfServiceBusRequests` and `paidServiceBusRequests`

Alternatively, you may be able to extend some of the implicit timeout periods.  Think about those services. is there anything there that could timeout?  Are we using an http client or sql client?  Those clients tend to have implicit, default timeouts that can be overridden in code.  I'd suggest hunting for any reference to any clients make web or db calls and searching for was extend their timeouts to max in order to mitigate the issue.  Another options might be trying to catch and handle these `System.OperationCanceledException` gracefuly.